# Stop caching of data on a ODBC - ACCESS php script

Tags: php, ms-access, caching, odbc

I got a PHP script that opens, make a query and closses the connection to an Access database usong ODBC.

The scripts measure the response time so i want to repeat the query several times.

Its not clear for me how the data is cached. The first time the query runs for 10 seconds and later for 0.0025 seconds. Any hint of how to stop this behevior?

```
PSEUDO:
<?PHP

for(i = 0 ;  i < 3 ; i++){
 $i = microtime(true);
 $conn_access = odbc_connect(conn);
 $rs_access = odbc_exec($conn_access,query);
 while ($fila = odbc_fetch_object($rs_access)){}    
 $f = microtime(true) - $i;
 echo $f;
 odbc_close ($conn_access); 
}

?>
```

Comment: Close and re-open the database each time. Access is purely filed-based, so once the connection's closed, any caches are flushed/dumped.

Comment: Sorry, my script did have a odbc_close instruction without success. I have updated the pseudocode. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to stop the caching? Just for speed testing?

Comment: There's also the OS file caches involved. Not sure how you'd tell Windows to flush those.

Comment: @Nanne, Yes this machine have several scripts that collects different stats and also do some backup stuff.

Comment: The Jet/ACE database engine has controls to flush the cache, but I'd have to look it up to find what they are. That won't do anything about the file caching, though.